# Binding a context menu command parameter to a datagrid property

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

In my XAML file I have a DataGrid with a context menu. The data source is a ViewModel which has a property `EntityCollection` (an ObservableCollection) as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid and another collection `ContextMenu.MenuItems` which serves as the data source to create a context menu on the DataGrid. The elements of that collection have a `Command` property which I bind to the Command property of the menu items:

```
<DataGrid Name="EntityDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding EntityCollection}" Height="450">
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenu.MenuItems}">
      <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
          <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
          <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                  Value="{Binding ElementName=EntityDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}" />
        </Style>
      </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

The action for the menu item command has the following signature in the ViewModel:

```
private void SelectedItemsAction(object parameter)
{
    // Do something with "parameter"
}
```

Now my problem is that I reach `SelectedItemsAction` when I click on a context menu item but the `parameter` is `null`. I believe that my problem is in the setter for the `CommandParameter` property. As you can see, I want to bind this property to the `SelectedItems` property of the DataGrid by setting the value to:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
        Value="{Binding ElementName=EntityDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

I've tried simpler values as a test:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
        Value="{Binding ElementName=EntityDataGrid, Path=Height}" />
```

Here `parameter` is still `null`. And then just to test if any parameter reaches my action method at all:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
        Value="10" />
```

This works, the `parameter` in my action method is now indeed `10`.

What am I doing wrong to bind the `CommandParameter` value to a property of `EntityDataGrid`? Is it possible at all?

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried doing an Ancestor binding?  Something like:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
        Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

Comment: Great, thank you, this works! (Now I only need to read a bit more about WPF binding to understand what your code is doing exactly ;))

Comment: It is walking up the tree to find an item that matches that type.  The first one it comes to it uses it as the binding context.

Comment: In the meantime I've read more about binding and now it's clear why my original markup didn't work and why your code is the correct way. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Unable to change this since it would just be a one-character edit, but you need one more closing bracket after `{x:Type DataGrid}}`

Answer (score 17):

The `ContextMenu` isn't in the same part of the Visual Tree so that's why you can't use ElementName etc. to reference the `DataGrid`. You'll have to use `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` instead. Try it like this

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenu.MenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},
                                    Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too! (I marked OffApps Cory's solution as accepted answer, just because he answered a few hours earlier. Anyway thanks for your effort!)

Comment: +1 Finally found it! This worked for me when using `RelayCommand` along with `CommandParameter` from the MVVM Light Toolkit. I wish WPF would make `ElementName` work regardless of where items were in the element tree. Thanks for sharing this `ContextMenu` binding variation!

Comment: I had the same experience with MVVM Light.   Tried all the usual stuff I know and had limited success, then quite a few other colleague suggestions and google-finds also failed.  But this answer was what I needed and taught me something new.  So thanks @Fredrik Hedblad 8 years later.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
    Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

If you use the code in the **CodeWarrior** answer, you can convert it to any type you want using the code below on the ViewModel side.

```
System.Collections.IList items = (System.Collections.IList)obj;
var collection = items.Cast<Foo>();
```

after that

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
.
.
```

but if you need a **single line** the following code will suffice.

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
```